# Ignore pep8(E501) in comments using visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, pep8

How can I ignore pep8 (E501) in Python comments using visual studio code. What I need is to ignore the warnings in Python comments, but not in Python codes. It seems that setting python.linting.pep8Enabled to false will ignore all warnings. How can I customize my setting.json?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had the same issue and I used

```
"python.linting.pep8Args": ["--ignore=E501"]
```

in my settings.json to ignore it.

Comment: But it will ignore all E501 warning including source codes, I just need to ignore comments.

Answer (score 1):

I usually start my comments with `noqa: E501`.

For example:

```
# noqa: E501 - Here, I can write my inline comment with more than 79 characters.
```